# How to update database with MyBatis?

Tags: java, mysql, maven, database-migration, mybatis

I use MyBatis, Java, Maven, MySQL and Eclipse IDE.

I have 2 dabases:
db1 and db2.

db1 - is my default database.

When in Maven I make migration:up it updates the database (schema) - db1.

How can I make migration:up with MyBatis to update database db2 too?

Answer (score 1):

Create another environment properties in environment folder and specify details of db2 there.

When you run `migration:up` this uses default environment from migration repository which is `development` (or in your case some other environment may be specified in mybatis migration maven plugin configuration). You need to create new file in migration repository for example `db2.properties` and then use it when running maven like this

```
mvn migration:up -Dmigration.env=db2
```